# Syntax error in partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am receiving a `syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting '}'` in my the following view code:

`<%= render :partial => 'form', :locals => { :message => @message, :user => @user} %>`

I am rendering the partial from my new.html page. The partial looks right to my eyes but perhaps I am missing something?

_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for message, :url => user_messages_path(user), :html => {:class => "MainForm"} do |f| %>

  <%if message.reply_to%>
    <%=f.hidden_field :to%>
    <%=f.hidden_field :parent_id%>
  <%else%>
    <%label{:for => 'message_to'} %>
      <%=:to.l%>
      <%em= "(" + :type_a_username.l + ")"%>
    <%= text_field_tag 'message[to]', @message.to, {:autocomplete => "off", :size => 35, :id => "message_to"}%>
    <% auto_complete%>#message_to_auto_complete
    <%content_for :end_javascript do%>
      <%= auto_complete_field 'message_to', {:url => auto_complete_for_username_user_messages_path(@user), :tokens=>','}%>

  <%if @reply  %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :subject  %>
  <%else%>
    <%label{:for => 'message_subject'}= :subject.l + ":"%>
    <%= f.text_field :subject%>

  <%label{:for => "message_body"}= :message.l + ":"%>
  <%= f.text_area :body%>

  <%p%>
    <%= submit_tag :send.l%>
```

Comment: Could you post your whole view?

Comment: As Vimsha said, we'll need to see a bit more; the error might not be on that line. Alternatively (I doubt it will resolve the issue), if you're using Ruby... 2.0 I believe it is, you can try the new hash syntax (for example: `render partial: 'form', locals: {message: @message, user: @user}`)

Comment: @PaulRichter, while the JSON-style notation has come into vogue as of Ruby 2.0, I don't think the hash-rocket notation has been deprecated... _yet_.

Comment: @zeantsoi Nope, you're right its still perfectly valid. Twas merely a general suggestion. Might help to remove a bit of noise to more easily spot syntax errors and omissions.

Comment: @Vimsha I posted the form view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `label` tag does not contain a hash. From [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-label):

```
<% f.label :message_to %>
```

The following line from your code looks particularly suspicious, and it certainly will throw an error. What are you trying to do with this exactly?

```
<%label{:for => 'message_subject'}= :subject.l + ":"%> # THIS WON'T WORK
```

If you want custom text for your label, you can accomplish it in the following manner:

```
<%= f.label :message_subject, "#{subject.l} :" %>
```

Which outputs the following markup:

```
<label for="message_subject">THE MESSAGE SUBJECT</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

This syntax here (and in similar places throughout your view):

```
<%label{:for => 'message_subject'}= :subject.l + ":"%>
```

is invalid.

A (generally) correct label element would be:

```
<%= f.label :subject %>
```

Remember a couple of things:

- Symbols (which is what that `:subject` is), are a special kind of object that ultimately represents an immutable string; it doesn't have that `.l` method you're expecting
- Assuming `:subject` is a field of `message`, ensure you're using the form builder object (the `f` variable in this case) so the form element is properly bound to the `message` object
- Form elements are echoed to the page using the `=` syntax in the ERB tag. It should always look like `<%= ... %>` if you want your code to render (or `<% ... %>` to suppress).

Comment: Thank you for explaining. I noticed that was throwing the error and now I understand how it all went wrong. Great notes!